# How can I rev my engine in drive while holding the brake and not stall?

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the engine stall out when you come to a stop with an automatic transmission?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3942/why-doesnt-the-engine-stall-out-when-you-come-to-a-stop-with-an-automatic-trans)

Occasionally I press both pedals simultaneously. I can feel my car trying to go forward and if I let off the brake a slight bit, I move. How can I do this without stalling like I would on a manual?